# How do I make a command block say the nearest player's name in chat in MC Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm working on a map in Bedrock Edition, and I need to have a command block at the end that says "Congratulations [player], you win!" Because it's a map, I cant just have it say a specific player's name, and I've seen maps that do exactly what I want mine to do. How do I format the command to allow this?

Comment: This is relatively easy in the Java Edition, but I'm not sure how you would do it Pocket Edition, unless `/tellraw` uses the same JSON formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with this command:

```
/say Congratulations @p, you win
```

You can use any other target selector if you prefer that, you can even use @a, or @e, which will return a list with all the specified players/entities, separated by `,`.

This, for example, will say "Congratulations Pig, Pig, Pig, you win", if there are 3, or more pigs in your world and you haven´t renamed them:

```
/say Congratulations @e[type=pig,c=3], you win
```

Comment: Duh, why didn't I think of this?