# How do I use target selectors to put player names in chat?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to know how to use target selectors such as `@p` and `@r` to display a person's gamertag in chat. I've tried to use `/tellraw @a {"rawtext":[{"text":"@p"}]}` but it just puts `@p` in chat, not any player names. Could anyone tell me how to get the selector to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a command block say the nearest player's name in chat in MC Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/353088/how-do-i-make-a-command-block-say-the-nearest-players-name-in-chat-in-mc-bedroc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct quote from the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Raw_JSON_text_format#Bedrock_Edition) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Raw_JSON_text_format&oldid=1543464#Bedrock_Edition)):

> Note that selectors such as "@a" and "@p" are not translated into player names

This feature simply does not exist in MCBE. Try "`/say @p`" instead.

Comment: OK. I wanted to know if there was a way around that so I could use target selectors with the tellraw command.

Comment: Only if you simulate the behaviour: Something like "if the closest player is called 'Horst', output 'Horst', if the closest player is called 'Karl', output 'Karl', …". That might work if you only play with a small number of friends and never anyone else.

Comment: I suppose that would be the optimal alternative although it is a bit limited.

Comment: It is very limited. The optimal solution is to play Java edition instead. :P